# Fill column value based on join in Pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe using the code

```
df = sc.parallelize([
    (123, 2345,25,""), (123, 2345,29,"NY"), (123,5422,67,"NY"),(123,9422,67,"NY"),(123,3581,98,"NY"),(231, 4322,77,""),(231,4322,99,"Paris"),(231,8342,45,"Paris")
]).toDF(["userid", "transactiontime","zip","location"])
```

```
+------+---------------+---+--------+
|userid|transactiontime|zip|location|
+------+---------------+---+--------+
|   123|           2345| 25|        |
|   123|           2345| 29|      NY|
|   123|           5422| 67|      NY|
|   123|           9422| 67|      NY|
|   123|           3581| 98|      NY|
|   231|           4322| 77|        |
|   231|           4322| 99|   Paris|
|   231|           8342| 45|   Paris|
+------+---------------+---+--------+
```

I want the output to be like this

```
+------+---------------+---+--------+
|userid|transactiontime|zip|location|
+------+---------------+---+--------+
|   123|           2345| 25|      NY|
|   123|           2345| 29|      NY|
|   123|           5422| 67|      NY|
|   123|           9422| 67|      NY|
|   123|           3581| 98|      NY|
|   231|           4322| 77|   Paris|
|   231|           4322| 99|   Paris|
|   231|           8342| 45|   Paris|
+------+---------------+---+--------+
```

I want to join on userid and transactiontime and fill the city column with the non-null values.

I have tried window function like this

```
w1 = Window.partitionBy('userid', 'transactiontime').orderBy(col('zip'))

df_new = df.withColumn("newlocation", F.last('location').over(w1))
print(df_new.show())
```

But this didn't work and i've tried self join as well but couldn't work that as well.
Any help ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`first`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.1/api/sql/index.html#first) and [`last`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.1/api/sql/index.html#last) windowing functions accept an optional `ignorenulls` parameter which may be helpful in this case.
However in your example you actually don't have null values but empty strings, which is different.

```py
w = Window.partitionBy('userid', 'transactiontime')

df_new = df \
    .withColumn("fixedLoc", F.when(F.col("location") == "", None).otherwise(F.col("location"))) \
    .withColumn("newLoc", F.first('fixedLoc', ignorenulls=True).over(w))
```

In the above solution, a temporary column is used to replace empty strings with null values, then `first` with `ignorenulls` is used on the new column.

As an alternative solution you can use the `max` function that will [ignore null values](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.1/sql-ref-null-semantics.html#builtin-aggregate-expressions-) and will prioritize non-empty strings:

```py
df_new = df \
    .withColumn("newLoc", F.max('location').over(w))
```